# Estimating Parameters of a Co-infection Model

Tags: python, modeling

I am working on a study on estimating parameters of a mathematical model on the co-infection of two diseases.

Is it possible to estimate in python the unknown parameters given that I don't have a data for the other disease? If it is, would you help me solve this problem?